# Getting started with Google Adword .net API

Tags: c#, google-ads-api

Most things that I've found about the .net AdWords API mention creating a bunch of settings for the application that will be used when you create an instance of the AdWordsUser class; however, I've had no luck with this.  My user always ends up nil and no settings are being read even though I named them as indicated in the AdWordsAppConfig class.

```
AdWordsAppConfig appConfig = new AdWordsAppConfig();
appConfig.AdWordsApiServer = "https://adwords-sandbox.google.com";
appConfig.Email = "fname.lname@gmail.com";
appConfig.Password = "password";
appConfig.DeveloperToken = "fname.lname@gmail.com++USD";

AdWordsUser user = new AdWordsUser();
```

The AdWordsUser has an overloaded constructor that accepts a dictionary of strings containing configuration parameters but doesn't have on that accepts an AdWordsAppConfig object.

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-dotnet/source/browse/trunk/src/AdWords/Lib/AdWordsAppConfig.cs

According to the AdWordsAppConfig class the following is used to retreive the settings when you call the constructor; however, how do you create a section called "AdWordsApi" in the App.Config?  I don't see that option in the settings editor.

```
ReadSettings((Hashtable) ConfigurationManager.GetSection("AdWordsApi"));
```

Any ideas on the proper way to set the configuration information and create the user instance that I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What Eric mentioned is the long-term solution, but if anyone is looking for a quick answer, this is how you do it:

```
AdWordsUser user = new AdWordsUser();
(user.Config as AdWordsAppConfig).Password = "XXXXX";
//TODO (Add more configuration settings here.

CampaignService campaignService = (CampaignService) user.GetService(AdWordsService.v201109.CampaignService);
//TODO (Add your code here to use the service.)
```

Cheers,
Anash

Comment: I prefer this method over what Google recommends.  I don't like messing with the web.config (or app.config) for this type of thing.  Especially useful if the info needs to come from user input or a database.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to post this question on the official AdWords API forum, as it is monitored by the current maintainers of that library:

http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/forum.html